# Something went wrong while saving the category. Notice: getimagesize():

Tags: magento2

I'm facing the following error when I try to change category name :

Something went wrong while saving the category.

```
Notice: getimagesize(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory in /home/nectarksa/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File/Mime.php on line 115
```

I've tried to increase php memory limit it's didn't fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the path give is the path to a directory/folder and not an image file.  So you need to do some debugging to see why.

```
if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
   $result = $this->getNativeMimeType($path);
} else {
   $imageInfo = getimagesize($path); // Line 115
   $result = $imageInfo['mime'];
}
```

Comment: Where I can put this code ?

Answer (score 0):

It's solved finally, the problem was because of one extension called auto cache flush.